# Is there a way to disable or freeze Gyroscope updates on a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm working with `video_360` from pub.dev and it comes enabled with Gyroscope sensing without any parameter to disable it.

I looked through all the source code but can't figure out where it is being read and updated.

Is there a way I can disable or freeze the gyroscope readings so that in such a plugin, the gyro sensor values would read the same values no matter how the phone is held?

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question in the Title, but for my specific scenario, since the package uses Exoplayer, the code for the sensors was inside it and that's why it was not in view inside the package source code.

This setter was what I needed: `setUseSensorRotation(bool)`.